# Обработка нескольких форм на странице одним скриптом AJAX без jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, form

Скрипт отлично обрабатывает одну из форм на странице, пробовал разные варианты чтобы обработать две и более форм, не смог, подскажите решение. привожу оригинал скрипта

```js
if (document.forms.form1 && window.FormData) {
  var form = document.forms.form1;
  
 var message = new Object();
 message.loading = 'Отправляем...';
 message.success = 'Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время ';
 message.failure = 'Что-то пошло не так ';
 var statusMessage = document.createElement('div');
 statusMessage.className = 'status';

 // форму скроем после отправки
    // var inputform = document.querySelector('.custom-form');
    // var formbutton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

 // Настройка AJAX запроса
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 request.open('POST', 'assets/hello.php', true);
 request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');

 // Добавляем обработчик на событие `submit`
 form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  form.appendChild(statusMessage);

  // Это простой способ подготавливить данные для отправки (все браузеры и IE > 9)
  var formData = new FormData(form);

  // Отправляем данные
  request.send(formData);

  // Функция для наблюдения изменения состояния request.readyState обновления statusMessage соответственно
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
   // <4 =  ожидаем ответ от сервера
   if (request.readyState < 4)
    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.loading;
   // 4 = Ответ от сервера полностью загружен
   else if (request.readyState === 4) {
    // 200 - 299 = успешная отправка данных!
    if (request.status == 200 && request.status < 300) {
     statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
     // скрываем форму и отправляем событие в метрику
     inputform.style.display = 'none';
     yaCounter53696953.reachGoal('formsubmit');
    }
    else
                    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure;
                    // formbutton.disabled = true;
     //form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', message.failure);
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST">
  <input name="name" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Форма 1</button>
</form>
<form name="form2" action="" method="POST">
  <input name="name" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Форма 2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо вынести сначала основные параметры отдельно, а для ворм ввести цикл.

У Вас в примере есть параметры `inputform` и `yaCounter53696953`, которые неизвестно откуда получены, а в остальном так:

```js
    var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    var message = new Object();
    message.loading = 'Отправляем...';
    message.success = 'Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время ';
    message.failure = 'Что-то пошло не так ';
    var statusMessage = document.createElement('div');
    statusMessage.className = 'status';


    for (let i=0;i<form.length;i++){
        form[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            form[i].appendChild(statusMessage);

            // Это простой способ подготавливить данные для отправки (все браузеры и IE > 9)
            var formData = new FormData(form[i]);

            // Настройка AJAX запроса
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('POST', 'assets/hello.php', true);
            request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');
            // Отправляем данные
            request.send(formData);

            // Функция для наблюдения изменения состояния request.readyState обновления statusMessage соответственно
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState < 4)
                    statusMessage.innerHTML = message.loading;
                else if (request.readyState === 4) {
                    if (request.status == 200 && request.status < 300) {
                        statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
                        inputform.style.display = 'none';
                        yaCounter53696953.reachGoal('formsubmit');
                    }
                    else
                        statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Форма 1</button>
</form>
<form name="form2" action="" method="POST">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <button type="submit">Форма 2</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Работает!!! Только есть ошибка при отправке более чем одной формы

Comment: @weinbrg Что за ошибка?

Comment: js1.js:25 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> это строка request.send(formData);

Comment: @weinbrg Ага. Перенесите строчки `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'assets/hello.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');` в функцию, перед `request.send(formData);`

Answer (score 4):

```
document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(item => { 
  item.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    var form = this;
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще одно решение от моего друга :)

```js
// обработчик всех форм
function formSubmitHandler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = event.target;
    
    var message = new Object();
    message.loading = 'Отправляем...';
    message.success = 'Мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время ';
    message.failure = 'Что-то пошло не так ';

    var statusMessage = document.createElement('div');
    statusMessage.className = 'status';

    // форму скроем после отправки
    // var inputform = document.querySelector('.custom-form');
    // var formbutton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

    // Настройка AJAX запроса
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'assets/hello.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');

    // Добавляем обработчик на событие `submit`
    // form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.appendChild(statusMessage);

    // Это простой способ подготавливить данные для отправки (все браузеры и IE > 9)
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    // Отправляем данные
    request.send(formData);

    // Функция для наблюдения изменения состояния request.readyState обновления statusMessageс
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        // <4 =  ожидаем ответ от сервера
        if (request.readyState < 4)
            statusMessage.innerHTML = message.loading;
        // 4 = Ответ от сервера полностью загружен
        else if (request.readyState === 4) {
            // 200 - 299 = успешная отправка данных!
            if (request.status == 200 && request.status < 300) {
                statusMessage.innerHTML = message.success;
                // скрываем форму и отправляем событие в метрику
                inputform.style.display = 'none';
                yaCounter53696953.reachGoal('formsubmit');
            }
            else
                statusMessage.innerHTML = message.failure;
                // formbutton.disabled = true;
                //form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', message.failure);
        }
    }
}

// Получаем список форм ...
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form.has-agreement');

for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    console.log(forms[i]);
    var form = forms[i];
    form.addEventListener('submit', formSubmitHandler);
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" class="has-agreement" action="" method="POST">
  <label for="agree1"><input id="agree1" class="agree" type="checkbox">Принять соглашение 1</label>
  <button type="submit">Записаться на курс 1</button>
</form>

<form name="form2" class="has-agreement" action="" method="POST">
  <label for="agree2"><input id="agree2" class="agree" type="checkbox">Принять соглашение 2</label>
  <button type="submit">Записаться на курс 2</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Рабочий каркас для нескольких форм с `fetch`.

Слегка не в тему сообщения, но навешать на него можно что угодно, при желании.

```js
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.form');

forms.forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', sendFormData);
});

async function sendFormData(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const form = event.target;

  const myFormData = new FormData(form);

  if (myFormData.has('userAccept', 'on')) {
    myFormData.set('subject', window.location.href);
    myFormData.set('title', 'Задайте свой вопрос');
    myFormData.delete('userAccept');
  } else {
    return console.log('error');
  }

  await fetch('http://website.ru/sender.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: myFormData
  });

  event.target.reset();
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Имя">
  <input type="tel" name="userPhone" placeholder="Телефон">
  <textarea name="userMessage" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>

  <label class="form-ask__accept">
    <input type="checkbox" name="userAccept" required> Ознакомлен и согласен
  </label>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
<br>
<form class="form">
  <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="Имя">
  <input type="tel" name="userPhone" placeholder="Телефон">
  <textarea name="userMessage" placeholder="Сообщение"></textarea>
  <label class="form-ask__accept">
    <input type="checkbox" name="userAccept" required> Ознакомлен и согласен
  </label>
  <button class="btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>

<!-- php-обработчик http://website.ru/sender.php -->
<!--
<? php
$c = true;

$name    =  trim(htmlentities($_POST['userName']));
$tel     =  trim(htmlentities($_POST['userPhone']));
$text    =  trim(htmlentities($_POST['userMessage']));
$subject =  trim(htmlentities($_POST['subject']));

$to      = "kubris.pro@gmail.com";
$date    = date("d.m.Y");
$time    = date("h:i");
$toSelf  = $to;


function adopt($txt) {
    return '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($txt).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($subject).'<'.$toSelf .'>' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($_POST as $key =>
$value ) {
    $msg .= "" 
        . ( ($c = !$c) ? '  <tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) 
        .   "<td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
            <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
            </tr>";
}

$msg = "<table style='width: 100%;'>"
    . " $msg"
    ."</table>";

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?> -->
```